# How to use routerLink with condition?

Tags: angular

I want to have condition for routerLink something like this

```
[routerLink] ="var ? ['test'] : []"
```

but this is not working. Any suggestion? Im using angular 4 so this is not working on this version.

Comment: It's working just fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/tZaD8dg1P461cn7gmqGi?p=preview (see the app/app.component.ts file). The problem is in your code. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: As @JB Nizet point, the following is from angular page example 

 <a [routerLink]="variable ? ['crisis-center'] : []" routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Center</a>

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<button *ngIf="condition" [routerLink]="['SomeRoute']></button>
<button *ngIf="!condition"></button>
```

Or put logic of 'SomeRoute' on your model and pass a variable to your routerLink

Answer (score 0):

Inside the [routerLink], I used condition attr(tested on Angular 14)

```
[routerLink]="[menuItem.children.length === 0 ? menuItem.pageUrl: '']"
```